# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Ed25519Key'

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

Below are the current settings on my system:
python : 2.7.14
paramiko (2.0.0)
bcrypt (3.1.3)
cryptography (2.0.3)
pyasn1 (0.3.6)
PyNaCl (1.1.2)

Comment: You need to give more information for us to be able to help you.  Post the code that is generating this error.

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko 2.0.0 definitely does not support Ed25519 keys.

You urgently need to upgrade.